# Bootstrap Collapsed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use this script

```
$(function () {
$('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) {
        children.hide('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    } else {
        children.show('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/

for recursive collapsible menu. It works perfectly. But I need the menu collapsed initially that is when the page load and expand only on click.

My JS knowledge is weak. But i tried using toggle(); and hide(); , it results in collapsed and doesnt expand on click

Below is recursive php code

```
<?php
function listroles($roles)
{
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach($roles as $role)
    {
        ?>
        <li>
            <span><i class="icon-plus "></i> Parent</span> <a href="<?php echo $role['category']->slug; ?>"><?php echo $role['category']->name; ?></a>
            <?php
            if ( ! empty($role['children']))
            {
                listroles($role['children']);
            }
            ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}

listroles($this->categories_menu);
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a css rule to hide the child li elements at the start

```
.tree li ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FKWE6/)

or hide the child li element on page load

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');

    //hide the child li elements
    $('.tree li ul > li').hide();
    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XBRRh/)

Comment: that works. Thanks. Is there any way i could make last child icon as 'icon-play', which would mean it's end(the last child).

Comment: @sumaise you mean the last level or the last child in each level

Comment: the level which is not expandable , so that it means end level and more expanding of this level

Comment: @sumaise why can't you change it in the html itself?

Comment: i use a recursive php code. I ll edit the post to show the funtion

Comment: i want to use this code i have copied it but its nor working properly

Comment: @MuneemHabib edit the fiddle to recreate the problem and post a new question

Comment: @ArunPJohny fiddle doesnt allow to download code. I want code so i can understand it properly

Comment: @MuneemHabib unless we know what is not working we won't be able to offer much help...

Comment: @ArunPJohny TREE VIEW is generated but there are no icons and its also not collapsing

Comment: one thing more i am getting warning(CSS3 draft syntax) in  .tree li::before and  .tree li::after

Comment: @MuneemHabib that is what I'm saying... copy your html and css to the fiddle and test it

Comment: If the tree is very large, what is the best way to organize a search on it? to open a branch and a necessary element in a tree?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to run the click() handler once.

```
$(function () {
     $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
       //blah blah blah
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).click();
});
```

edit: forgot some code